# Garbage free String class using StringBuilder reflection does not properly initialize

Tags: c#, string, xna, garbage-collection, xna-4.0

I am trying to create a custom StringBuilder class based on the comments [here](http://www.gavpugh.com/2010/03/23/xnac-stringbuilder-to-string-with-no-garbage/).

This is my current code:

```cs
class MyStringBuilder
{
    public StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    public String linkToStringBuilderString;

    public MyStringBuilder(int maxCapacity)
    {
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(maxCapacity, maxCapacity);

        linkToStringBuilderString = (String)stringBuilder.GetType().GetField("m_StringValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(stringBuilder);
    }
};
```

However, the last line of the constructor that should obtain the permanent link to the internal StringBuilder string gives my a null reference compile error and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break down the line that's failing.

I mean it.  Literally.  It's doing way too much, making it difficult to debug, as you've discovered.  So let's rewrite it.

```
linkToStringBuilderString = (String)stringBuilder.GetType().GetField("m_StringValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(stringBuilder);
```

That's doing a lot of stuff.  Let's put each operation onto its own line:

```
var type = stringBuilder.GetType();
var field = type.GetField("m_StringValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var value = (String)field.GetValue(stringBuilder);
```

Now Visual Studio should give you a clearer picture of what's failing when an exception is thrown.

When I run this code, I get a `NullReferenceException` on this line:

```
var value = field.GetValue(stringBuilder);
```

Which means that `field` is null.  Why might that be the case?  Well, `GetField()` returns null if the field you've requested doesn't actually exist.  This is what happens when you rely on the internal implementation details of BCL classes.

Opening up the `StringBuilder` class in dotPeek (it's in `mscorlib`), I see no member named `m_StringValue`.  The string is stored using a series of dynamically allocated arrays; it doesn't appear to be cached in string form.

Looking at version 2.0 of `mscorlib`, I see that there *used* to be a field with this name.  So this class was apparently refactored when .NET 4 came out.  Again, these are the problems with taking a dependency on internal implementation details.

There is [another article](http://www.gavpugh.com/2010/12/21/xnac-stringbuilder-changes-in-xna-4-0/) on the site you linked detailing exactly this issue.  Hopefully, this answer will help you point yourself in the right direction in the future.